# Firebase Email Link only for existing users (forbid new users)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

How one can forbid new users to sign in using Firebase Email Link? So only exiting customers can sign in.

I want to register only users that will subscribe via Stripe and create new account server-side.

Also, if I may do it in the same thread: how can I edit email template that is sent to the new user? In console this one is not available.

Comment: There is no way to prevent users from signing up with Firebase Authentication. You should see it as a pure authentication solution: it allows the user to prove who they are. Typically when a developer asks for this, they're actually looking for an *authorization* solution instead, which determines what a user is allowed to do. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+prevent+new+users and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+authorization+disable

Comment: I see. Is then there any solution for this: I have a subscription-based SaaS and I want people to be signed up once they pay. Also, to let them log in. Because of that I don't want free users to register. Is there any way to achieve that with Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to prevent new email signups with Firebaseui 4.0.8 (https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/99#issuecomment-794537000), but then how will they subscribe with Stripe?

Instead, let them sign up but only allow them to use your service if they have the custom claim set by the Stripe Firebase Extension.

See:
https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-stripe-subscriptions?authuser=0