# Firebase sign user up only after successful payment

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement the following flow:

1. User enter website
2. User clicks `Subscribe now`
3. User gets redirected to `Stripe Checkout` (because it's easier)
4. User successfully pays
5. User now can sign in (or even better - is automatically signed in)
6. User is charged every month automatically and so is updated database (to control access)

Long story short: give user an access only when he paid.

I'm using Firebase for that, but it seems like there are many roadblocks/headaches:

- I can't disable sign up (ideally it should be only via subscription)
- [Magic Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) is not much more helpful because [you can't change email template sent to the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779992/firebase-email-link-only-for-existing-users-forbid-new-users)
- in [official example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js) it looks a bit daunting without much of explanation (specially regarding webhooks which are the basis of subscription model)

I looked all around the web about subscription model while using Firebase, but there are almost none.

My question is: anyone implemented subscription service with **Stripe** (any, doesn't have to be Checkout - flow is the same) and **Firebase**? Or should I go for my own server and use Firebase only for database?

I really don't find it as a good UX when user has to first sign up and then pay (too much friction).

Comment: I am facing the exact same situation now. Wondering what solution you chose. Mind sharing some details as an answer here?

Comment: Giving a user access only when logged in is not really possible. However you can control what a user can see with custom claims, only given to users who bought a subscription. Hence, that is what you also see on most websites, a “free” area and “premium” pages/content.

Answer (score 0):

**Using cloud functions:**

1. create a stripe customer during checkout.

```
stripe.customers.create({ email: 'user_email' }) // grab customer id
```

2. create firebase user document and save the stripe customer id into 'users' collection.

(use `userRecord.uid` id into `doc()` id)

```
  firebaseAdmin.auth().createUser({
      email: 'email',
      password: 'temporary_password',
      displayName: 'fullname'
    })
    .then((userRecord) => {
      return firebaseAdminSDK.firestore()
        .collection('users').doc(userRecord.uid)
        .set({ stripe_account: 'cus_HILXPWljT9fKRA' })
    })
```

- send email to user
- send email & password back to client.

**On client-side:**

3. after receiving successful message from cloud function server, let user sign in automatically

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
```

4. when user logs in grab the `stripe_account` from users collection and fetch stripe subscription status and show it to user.
5. ask user verify its email or change password. disable all editing until user verifies its email or changes its password.

Comment: Couple of questions: 1. Create customer while [creating session](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/subscriptions/starting#create-checkout-session) on the backend? 2. What email you have in mind to send to user? 3. Is it safe to walk around with password throughout multiple API requests?

Comment: 1. create a [customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create) and then move on to session using customer id
2. on client side make email field required so user can enter email
3. you can secure your endpoints using [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims), on your backend limit users actions if email not verified

Comment: My question number 3 about safety was more about if credentials should be passed so freely. After all they are sensitive data and custom claims are something else. Maybe sending token would be better? And why not create customer after successful payment?

Comment: yea, then maybe signInAnonymously() is better solution after successful payment.

Comment: @jeand'arme how did you end up doing this? Looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking about the following setup using the firebase Stripe extension:

1. User fills in e-mail address and clicks submit.
2. `signInAnonymously()` is called and user e-mail adress is set with `updateEmail()`.
3. Then a checkout sessions is created with the uid attached:

   ```
   async stripeCheckout({ state }, payload) {
     const uid = state.authUser.uid
     const ref = await this.$fire.firestore
       .collection('users')
       .doc(uid)
       .collection('checkout_sessions')
       .add({
         price: payload.price,
         success_url: SUCCES_URL,
         cancel_url: CANCEL_URL,
       });
     // Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
     ref.onSnapshot((snap) => {
       const { error, url } = snap.data();
       if (error) {
         // Show an error to your customer and
         // inspect your Cloud Function logs in the Firebase console.
         alert(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
       }
       if (url) {
         // We have a Stripe Checkout URL, let's redirect.
         window.location.assign(url);
       }
     })
   }
   ```
4. CANCEL_URL can be any url
5. SUCCESS_URL will be an url + query parameter with the e-mail
6. Behind the SUCCESS_URL you'll call `sendSignInLinkToEmail()`
7. In stripe you set a custom claim in your subscription, for example: `stripeRole` equals `premium`. This claim will be added to firebase auth for subscribed users only.
8. Your frontend can use an auth guard or middleware to check for the custom claim
9. If you use firestore to serve content to premium members, you should use security rules like: `request.auth.token.stripeRole == "premium";`